# How to find bunch of closest strings?

Tags: string, image, matlab, signals

I have a string and a pattern. How I can use strfind in matlab and find a bunch of the closest strings? In other words, strfind finds the exact match while I am interested to find a bunch of the closest strings (e.g. 10 closest strings)

Comment: Close in which metric?

Comment: I think you'll find [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/18932) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [this](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17585-calculation-of-distance-between-strings/content/strdist.m) function `strdist` from the file exchange, which computes the Levenshtein distance between two strings.

Here's a convenient wrapper function. You give it a single string `str` and an array of strings `strarray` (and optionally a number of strings to return `n`) and it gives you a cell array containing the closest `n` strings:

```
function result = strfuzzy(str,strarray,n)
#STRFUZZY
#
#   Inputs
#       str         String
#       strarray    Cell array of strings
#       n           Integer, 1 <= n <= length(strarray)
#
#   Outputs
#       result      Cell array of length n containing the closest matches to str
#

if nargin < 2, error('Requires at least two arguments'), end
if nargin < 3, n = length(strarray); end

A = cellfun( @(x) strdist(str,x), strarray );
[tmp,idx] = sort(A);
result = strarray(idx);
result = result(1:n);

end
```

Here's how to use it:

```
>> strarray = {'cat', 'hey', 'hay', 'hat', 'Hey'};
>> strfuzzy('hey', strarray)
ans = 
    'hey'    'hay'    'Hey'    'hat'    'cat'
>> strfuzzy('bat', strarray, 3)
ans = 
    'cat'    'hat'    'hay'
```